# Laravel Get the Top 5 IDs with the Most Records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a table called `errors` with the following fields: `id, website_id, message & level.` I'm trying to get the top 5 websites with the most errors.

**Query**

`SELECT website_id, COUNT(id) AS 'errors' 
    FROM errors GROUP BY website_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`

I have no clue how to do this with the Laravel Query Builder and Eloquent. Can anyone help me out?

**Database Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [`DB::raw("{query}")`](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_raw) function to execute your raw query.

But if you want to use eloquent, you will have to use relations and query these. For example, if you have a `Website` model with a relation to an `Error` model, you can do the following to get the website models with the most errors:

```
Website::withCount('errors')            // Count the errors
    ->orderBy('errors_count', 'desc')   // Order by the error count
    ->take(5)                           // Take the first 5
    ->get();
```

Comment: Your solution also looks like it works, so I'm going to try that aswell! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @KoenvandeSande if I were you, I'd use this Eloquent solution instead of using raw queries.

Comment: Ye, Im going to try both ways and look which one is the best and most usefull for my application. @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: Your solution is indeed better, again thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

This may be helpful.

```
    $result = Website::selectRaw("website_id,count(id) as errors")
              ->groupBy('website_id')
              ->orderBy('errors','DESC')
              ->limit('5')
              ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results

```
$errors = DB::table('errors')
        ->select('website_id', DB::raw('COUNT(id) as errors'))
        ->groupBy('website_id')
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(id)'), 'DESC')
        ->take(10)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Works for me! Thanks.

Comment: Welcome :) Goodluck

Answer (score 1):

Try this simplified version for laravel eloquent;

```
$some_data = YourModel::select('column_name')
            ->groupBy('column_name')
            ->orderByRaw('COUNT(*) DESC')
            ->take(5)
            ->get();
```